# Is using 'forever' still the suggested approach to run nodejs as a linux/unix service?

Tags: node.js, service, forever

In the past couple of years NodeJS became a major player in the server landscape - and I really find it hard to believe that there is no decent way to have nodejs run as a service on a linux box. On Windows we have iisnode - but for non Windows environments the forever package is suggested as the way to go - instead of a real solution.

Is there maybe a servicized version of nodejs out there that I could not locate?

Comment: suggested by.... whom? each dev will have their own preferred package to use when there are several to choose from.

Comment: well whatever surrogate stuff - forever being the most prominen at least on SO.

Comment: yeah I dont want a preferred package :) I want something in nodejs to have support for what most people uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a "servicized" version of Node.js available in the sense you are thinking. Keeping your Node application running (for example in the event of a fatal error) is up to you entirely.

As suggested in the first comment, this is fairly subjective, but really there are two big packages (and one or two alternative methods) for making a service out of your Node application. As you've mentioned, [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) is a popular choice. If you've never taken a look at [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), I suggest doing so, as it offers some services that forever does not. Alternatively, you could search for information on [supervisord](https://serversforhackers.com/process-monitoring/), which I've had success with in the past. Finally, daemonizing Node with [upstart](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-a-linux-daemon-with-node-js-on-a-vps) is something to look at if the others don't fit well for you.