# Google Cloud/AWS: How to start NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, web-services, amazon-web-services, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS server on GCP and AWS. I have created instances with Bitnami Linux image and uploaded my files. I can SSH in to the instance and start the server by running `node` command.
But how can I run the server permanently?
I tried putting the process to background but it stopped soon as I logged off SSH.
What is the correct way to starting the server process.

I added a script as follows:

```
key: startup-script
value: node /home/madu/nodeapp/bin/www
```

And restarted the VM. But still doesn't look like it works.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the server OS?

Comment: Did you search for anything before posting this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486295/is-using-forever-still-the-suggested-approach-to-run-nodejs-as-a-linux-unix-se http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850777/how-to-run-a-node-js-app-in-background-on-azure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273993/nodejs-forever-how-to-run-my-npm-application

Answer (score 2):

If you have the permission, install tmux, which is a terminal multiplexer. You can also use GNU screen, ect. 
Do the following

```
ssh into the remote machine
start tmux by typing tmux into the shell
start node inside the started tmux session
leave/detach the tmux session by typing Ctrl+B and then D
```

You can now safely log off from the remote machine, your process will keep running inside tmux. When you come back again and want to check the status of your process you can use tmux attach to attach to your tmux session.

If you want to have multiple sessions running side-by-side, you should name each session using *Ctrl-B* and *$*. You can get a list of the currently running sessions using *tmux list-sessions.*

tmux can do much more advanced things 
https://tmux.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying on Compute Engine? Why not use App Engine Flex? It's much simpler than trying to install Node.js on your own on Compute Engine. Here's how to deploy Node.js on App Engine:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine

Comment: Thank you. Yes I'm using compute engine. I wanted to do it manually than deploying through the app engine. I will give this a try later.